# Filter objects or (if 0 found) get all objects in Django with one DB hit

Tags: django, django-queryset

Is there a way in Django to achieve the following in one DB hit (Debug Toolbar shows 2 queries)?

```
q = SomeModel.objects.filter(name=name).order_by(some_field)
if q.count() == 0:
    q = SomeModel.objects.all().order_by(some_field)
```

I want to check if there are objects with a given name. If yes, then return them. If not, return all objects. All done in one query.

I've checked Subquery, Q, conditional expressions but still don't see how to fit it into one query.

Comment: I can't think of a way offhand, but just out of curiosity why is it so important to do it with one db hit?  What you have is very readable and only incurs an extra db hit if there are no named objects.  Could be slightly improved with `q.exists()` instead of `q.count() == 0`, but otherwise looks good to me.

Comment: I have 2 models with such requests for an index page. If not considering 1 user query and using select_related, I've got 4 queries. I started to think if I could make it in 2 queries instead. I expect those 2 models to store many rows and want to make the index page as light as possible.

Comment: Still seems to me it's not too much of an issue.  I think this falls under Knuth's "premature optimization" rule.  I'd wait until you start seeing increased response time, then profile and try to improve.  But again: I don't know how to "coalesce" the whole query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, much as I resisted (I still think it's premature optimization), curiosity got the better of me.  This is not pretty but does the trick:

```
from django.db.models import Q, Exists

name_qset = SomeObject.objects.filter(name=name)
q_func = Q(name_exists=True, name=name) | Q(name_exists=False)
q = SomeModel.objects.annotate(
    name_exists=Exists(name_qset)
).filter(q_func).order_by(some_field)
```

Tried it out and definitely only one query.  Interesting to see if it is actually appreciably faster for large datasets...

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it out tomorrow. Also I found that it can be done with intersection. I posted an example. Checked and it seems to work.

Comment: I've made a mistake - with intersection sometimes won't work. Will apply your solution.

Comment: yeah, I saw that

Comment: Tried your solution in my code. Works. Quite a complicated query under hood. And it is indeed interesting if it is actually appreciably faster. Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You best bet is to use `.exists()`, otherwise your code is fine

```
q = SomeModel.objects.filter(name=name).order_by(some_field)
if not q.exists():
    q = SomeModel.objects.all().order_by(some_field)
```

Comment: It is fine but exists() or count() is not a question here. I've got 2 models and thus 4 queries, but I thought if I could make it in 2 DB hits to make the index page lighter if possible. I know it might seem like micro optimization but still keeps bothering me.

Comment: Perhaps its the `order_by()` that is an extra query? Did you try removing it from both the `filter()` and `.all()`, and then adding it in the end via `q = q.order_by(some_field)`?

Comment: I tried `q = Model.objects.filter(name=name)` and `if not q.exists(): q = q.all()` , but still 2 queries.